# Getting windows 7 to boot from external hard drive. Using Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS as my current operating system, and I have a Windows 7 iso on a disk. I'm using an external hard drive because my internal hard drive has become damaged. I need to get Windows to install onto my external hard drive (where Ubuntu is as well). The iso disk will not install windows to the hard drive. Can anyone help guide me through the process of getting windows on the external?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backup your documents onto an external disk (or DVDs)
2. Via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), make >40Go free space on your external disk (the one containing Ubuntu), and format this free space into NTFS.
3. Run the Windows installer and select the external disk for installation.

Answer (score -1):

I found how to boot windows 7 on a external hard drive by using a program called PWBoot.

Again, the name is PWBoot.

It took me ages to find a program like this.

All you have to do is install windows Vista or windows 7 by connecting the drive on ata or ide. Then after the installation is over, you boot into windows and install the program PWBoot. From that moment on, your hard drive will be able to boot from a USB. Sweet uh?